# Физический 3d движок на java

Tags: java, 3d, движок, физика

Ищу физический движок на джаве для задачи перемещение объектов по 3d-ландшафту. Т.е. базовый функционал, который необходим - это определение коллизий и возможность передвинуть объект в горизонтальной плоскости так, чтобы он автоматически принял необходимое положение на вертикальной оси (чтобы он лежал на поверхности ландшафта в нужной точке).

Дополнительное условие - он нужен для сервера, а как следствие желательно чтобы он работал побыстрее и имел минимум лишних частей.

Какие есть варианты движков и правилен ли вообще такой подход для данной задачи?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Есть пара реализаций для Java:

- **JBullet:** http://jbullet.advel.cz/
- **ode4j**: https://github.com/tzaeschke/ode4j