# Одинаковая симуляция физики на разных устройствах

Tags: java, физика, движок

Использую `bullet` - физический движок, но не могу добиться одинаковой симуляции на разных устройствах. Подскажите, в каком направлении двигаться. Может есть, подходящий для этих целей, физический движок твердых тел?

Comment: Напиши, в чем возникает различие. Из вопроса не понятно, в чем проблема

Comment: С начальными параметрами одинаковыми(импульс, скорость и положение) резльтат отличается. Даже при многократом прогоне на одной машине есть небошьшие различия. Мне кажется движок не совсем детерминирован, но куда копать я не знаю.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Причина в том, что многие физические движки написаны на C/C++ и работают с числами с плавающей запятой.

А при работе с плавающей запятой может возникнуть потеря точности на младших разрядах(+ особенность реализаций архитектур процессоров) и данная погрешность может аккумулироваться при последовательности вычислений, можно про это прочитать [статью на хабре](https://habrahabr.ru/post/219595/).

Java-движки являются адаптерами для работы с этими библиотеками.
Как вариант, можно попробовать другие библиотеки, [тут рекомендуют jbox2d для 2d вычислений](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11200428/java-physics-engine) или [тут пару вариантов для 3d вычислений](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/571517/%D0%A4%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9-3d-%D0%B4%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B6%D0%BE%D0%BA-%D0%BD%D0%B0-java?rq=1). Нужно смотреть опытным путем насколько велика погрешность.

Также точность вычислений можно повысить путем оптимизации своих формул, что бы меньше была погрешность на начальных этапах вычислений(например операцию деления делать как можно позже)